# How accurate is the firebase forge analytics

Tags: firebase

I have 506.96 KB of test data stored in a firebase db. Just refreshing the forge a dozen times without opening the child sent my bandwidth use to 10 mb. The weird thing is that the bandwidth use keeps on going up and down. From 10mb it went down to around 7.7mb and then up to 15mb.

Does refreshing the forge download all of firebase's data? Is there a way to see the bandwidth data without affecting it?

Is the bandwidth data accurate? How is it estimated? It seems far too high. I have another database where I'm doing development on. After about 3 weeks of moderate use by 1 person (me) I have racked up 3.5GB of bandwidth use. That seems incredibly high and is on track for more than $10/user/month which is just ridiculous.

Comment: See Rob's answer below. I agree that 3.5GB for one users seems insanely high. For most apps that's enough for hundreds or thousands of users. I suspect you are syncing more data than you realize. Perhaps you are forgetting to use limit() appropriately? Or are reading at the root when you should be accessing specific paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, loading Firebase Forge will also load all of the data for that Firebase for display in the Graphical Debugger. As a result, each refresh of Forge will cause your bandwidth usage to increase by the amount of data you have stored in your Firebase (assuming you're loading Forge at the root).

Some ways to reduce this include just leaving Forge open to observe changes rather than refreshing it entirely, or visiting defined paths with less data than the root in order to load less data.

If you'd like to review the data for a specific Firebase, reach out to support@firebase.com. Hope that helps!

Comment: Why does the bandwidth number go up and down?

Comment: While I wouldn't expect the total 30-day bandwidth number to fluctuate highly, it could be that some values have fallen out of the 30-day sliding window. We're going to dig into this internally to verify your statistics - can you reach out to support email listed above?

Comment: @RobDiMarco  It's still fluctuating. As we were doing a test to understand how bandwidth is calculated, we inserted 100 rows of size100bytes each and a addChildEventListener to get the update on adding each child. Bandwidth was 143.07kb ->after 5mins -> 219.82kb -> 143.47kb -> 220.52kb?  Is there any calculator to calculate bandwidth? We want to calculate our cost so that we can finalize user subscription price in our app. Thanks in advance.